# Hibernate Second Level Cache In Case of Soft Delete

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

Read operations are very high as compare to insert/update/delete for master data module. We are using JDBC for read,write and update operations till now. We are doing soft delete (Marking IS_DELETED column to 'Y') on delete operation. All write/update methods are synchronized to handle the concurreny. We are using oracle and have no plan to support multiple databases.

Now, We are planning to cache the data and we also have plans to go for clustering.

The easiest option we have is to change the insert/update/delete methods and use something like ehcache to manage the cache as per our requirement and handle concurrency in the clustered environment by using version column in the table and remove synchronized keyword.

Other option that people around me are suggesting (Infact asking me to do) is to move to the hibernate (I don't know much about hibernate) which will take care of caching and concurrency automatically.

Here are my doubts:

1) Is it worth to change the complete DAO code given we have around 200 tables to mangage the master data ?.

2) Would hibernate second level cache help in this case given we need to filter the cached data again to discard deleted rows or there is a mechanism in hibernate (or any other way) by which we can perform update operation in database but delete operation in the cached data ?

3) We have exposed the data transfer objects to other modules having all the fields of the table with primary key stored in the separate PK Objects (Having Primary key fields in a separate object) and we don't have reference DO in it (Composite DO are not there). Given, We can't afford to change the exposed methods and DO structure - so do we have to pack the hibernate cached entities data in our DO again ? Or we can reuse the old DO structure as hibernate entity (As Per my understaindg PK column should be there directly in the hibenate entity rather than being in some composite object). I mentioned composite DO because we also have dependent dropdown requirement which could have been used with hibernate lazy loading for the child objects if we would have composite DO at the first place. Argument against is to provide new methods which would use cached data and depricate the old methods. Other modules would slowly migrate as per their need on caching but we will have maintaince issues as we have to maintain both methods in case of the db changes. Also, 1 and 2 doubts are still there.

I am sure that hibernate is not the way to go for us at this stage and I have to convince people around me but I want to know your views on long term advantages of moving to hibernate other than automatic management of second level cache, concurrency handling (Can we done by small code change at common place) and db indepedency (We are not interested in) on the cost of changing the complete code.

Comment: One more point to consider: Updating or inserting data into db via hibernate cannot be done in a batch. If you need to update more than one dataset with one query you have to use native queries. In order to get the current version of your dataset you have to evict the second level cache.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to migrate to hibernate you should take in account
1) You'll need to map all your structure to POJO's (if you have not already)
2) Rewrite all DAO's to use hibernate (bare in mind, that hibernate QL/criteria API has certain limitations
3) Be ready to fight lazy initialization problems and so on...
Personaly i don't thinks it's worth migrating to hibernate with working model unless it's extremly painfull to maintain current model

Concerning your 2 and 3 questions
2) Second level cache holds only loaded instances, accessed by primary key. i.e. if you say hibernateSession.load(User, 10) - it will lookup User object in second level cache using id=10. If i understand clearly that's not the case. Most of the time you want to load your data using more complex query - in that case you will need StandarQueryCache, which will map your query string to a list of loaded IDs which in turn will be retrieved from second-level cache. But if you have a lot of queries with a low similarity - both StandartQueryCache and second level cache will be total useless (take a look http://darren.oldag.net/2008/11/hibernate-query-cache-dirty-little_04.html)
3)You can use components and such, but im not sure about your DTO structure.

Hope that helps

Comment: Second level cache does **not** hold the loaded instances. Its like a hash map where the key is the pk and the entry is an array of the values of the cached dataset. This means altering the instances does not alter the cache.

Comment: One thing to add to question 2) If you select data from 2level cache using hibernate and change the data. The cached data will not be change. So if an other session reads the same data it will not get the most current state of the data. To solve this you can evict the cache by your self or you can wait until the cache times out. So Hibernate does not help you to keep the cache up to date.